Where is EVM state and transaction journal stored?
The question of where and how special data structures are stored (and appear!) on the node: the state of the EVM (where the current values of all variables of all smart contracts are stored) and the transaction log in Ethereum. I need a direct accurate understanding of WHERE the storage status and transaction log are located. Are they removed from the block chain by each new node (which has just appeared on the network and requested ONLY a copy of the block chain)? Or they are directly requested from other nodes (in parallel with the block chain) - that is, they are requested: the block chain, the state of the EVM (or is it being removed from the block chain?), the transaction log (or is it being removed from the block chain?)
P. S. I've seen the answer to a similar question, but it doesn't satisfy me, since it's a little bit about something else: Where is the state data stored?

Please, read the section TRIES IN ETHEREUM https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/data-structures-and-encoding/patricia-merkle-trie/
